# Assembly program to reverse a string terminates after printing one character

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to write an assembly program that takes in a string of length 5 and prints the reversed string. I tried to print the characters one by one in reverse order by using a loop with ecx = 5. To print the characters I calculate the reversed address and then use a subroutine to print that character.

But there seems to be a mistake in my code, it only outputs the first character.

For example for a given input `12345` I'm getting `1` as output but I expected it to print `54331`

```
segment .bss
    INPT: resb 5

segment .text
        global  asm_main
asm_main:
    mov eax, 3              ; system call no (sys_read = 3)
    mov ebx, 1              ; std_in = 1
    mov ecx, INPT           ; ptr to location to store input (INPT)
    mov edx, 5              ; no of bytes to read
    int 0x80                ; issue a system call

    mov ecx, 5
swap:
    mov edx, -8
    imul edx, ecx
    add edx, 40
    add edx, INPT           ; address of next byte to print = [INPT + 5 * 8 - ecx * 8]
    call print
    loop swap
    jmp exit
print:
    push ecx
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, edx
    mov edx, 1 
    int 0x80
    pop ecx
    ret
exit:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> INPT: resb 5
> ```

This reserves 5 **bytes**.
But the calculation has next comment

> ; address of next byte to print = [INPT + 5 * 8 - ecx * 8]

expecting **qword** elements!

Even if you corrected the above via changing -8 to -1, you would still not **reverse** the input! A `lea  ecx, [INPT + ecx - 1]` can do the trick.

Additionally note that `STDIN` = 0 and that `sys_read` returns a count that you should use instead of that fixed number 5.
Also don't use the slow `LOOP` instruction and why not call *print* with the address ready in the `ECX` register.
Lastly, you could loop using a register that is not clobbered by the calls that follow. This saves on pushing and popping.

To reverse the print use this:

```
asm_main:
  mov eax, 3              ; system call no (sys_read = 3)
  xor ebx, ebx            ; std_in = 0
  mov ecx, INPT           ; ptr to location to store input (INPT)
  mov edx, 5              ; no of bytes to read
  int 0x80                ; -> EAX

  mov edi, eax
swap:
  lea  ecx, [INPT + edi - 1]  ; address of next byte to print in reverse order
  call print
  dec  edi
  jnz  swap
  jmp  exit
print:
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov edx, 1 
  int 0x80
  ret
exit:
  mov eax, 1
  xor ebx, ebx
  int 0x80
```